# How can I query GcmNetworkManager to see if my task is scheduled or not?

Tags: android, gcm-network-manager

I have scheduled a task to run periodically using `GcmNetworkManager`, but I don't want it to be persisted, because I don't want to add `android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` to list of the permissions my application requires. So, I am currently scheduling the task in `onCreate()` of my main activity. I was wondering, is there a way to query `GcmNetworkManager` about my task and if it has already been scheduled, skip this?

Answer (score 2):

There is method in `Task.Builder` called `setUpdateCurrent`([link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/Task.Builder.html#public-methods)). 
It is optional setter to specify whether this task should override any preexisting tasks with the same tag. This defaults to false, which means that a new task will not override an existing one.

Hope it helps

Comment: I know about this method but it is like creating the whole task and then letting GC take care of it. I was hoping to determine whether my task is there before actually creating a new one